# Google Documents List API - problem retrieving a list of documents

Tags: google-api

I'd like to get a list of my documents from google docs api. First I get a authValue using ClientLogin, then I send a request to that url https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full with header set to "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=authValue", but I always get a response "Authorization required". What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you request the token with the "writely" service when performing ClientLogin.  Also, make sure that you're sending the token provided after Auth= in the ClientLogin response.

```
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=DQAAA...
```